# If I run a loop a million times, do I have to worry about declaring doubles in each iteration?

Tags: c, memory-management

I run a loop a million times. Within the loop I call a C function to do some math (generating random variables from various distributions, to be exact). As part of that function, I declare a couple of `double` variables to hold parts of the transformation. An example:

```
void getRandNorm(double *randnorm, double mean, double var, int n) 
{
    // Declare variables
    double u1;
    double u2;
    int arrptr = 0;
    double sigma = sqrt(var); // the standard deviation

    while (arrptr < n) { 
        // Generate two uniform random variables
        u1 = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        u2 = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;

        // Box-Muller transform
        randnorm[arrptr] = sqrt(-2*log(u1))*cos(2*pi*u2)*sigma+mean;
        arrptr++;
        if (arrptr < n) { // for an odd n, we cannot add off the end
            randnorm[arrptr] = sqrt(-2*log(u2))*cos(2*pi*u1)*sigma+mean;
            arrptr++;
        }
    }   
}
```

And the calling loop:

```
iter = 1000000 // or something
for (i = 0; i < iter; i++) {

    // lots of if statements
    getRandNorm(sample1, truemean1, truevar1, n);

    // some more analysis
}
```

I am working on speeding up the runtime. It occurs to me that I don't know what is happening with all these `double` variables that I am declaring. I assume a new 8 byte chunk of memory is allocated for the double for each of the one million loops. What happens to all those memory locations? They are declared within a C function; do they survive that function?  Are they still locked up until the script exits?

The context for this question is wrapping this C program into a python function. If I'm going to execute this function multiple times in parallel from python, I want to be sure that I'm being as thrifty with memory usage as possible.

Comment: 'I declare a couple of double variables' - where? What storage class?  Code pleeeze.  You're prolly OK 'cos automatic storage, but we need to see...

Comment: Technically, there are C programs, not scripts.

Comment: Oh, there: 'double u1; double u2;?   They're fine - automatic storage duration.

Comment: The only way you will kown is meassure. Google Benchmark is a great tool.

Comment: You currently pass `pi` (aka π) to the function.  It isn't clear why you make it take that parameter.  You could use a constant — for the most part, the value of π doesn't change much.  This would marginally improve performance.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, I realized that as I was posting here. I was debating whether I could fix it in my own program before someone called me out. I was called out first.

Comment: When I implemented similar code, I used a structure to contain control information, including a seed value, and I used the POSIX-defined [`erand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/erand48.html) function so that the random number sequence for the Gaussian values would be independent of any other random number generating activity in the same program.  The `drand48()` family of functions is often a bit better as a PRNG than the default `rand()` — but it does vary between systems.  I've not benchmarked for the utmost speed, or provided a way to get multiple values.

Comment: Does wrapping up in python means.... are you going to invoke this compiled C program from Python in parallel. I didn’t get the context. In C calling a function will create a function frame in call stack allocating memory for all variables used in function. Once this function is completed the created function frame will be discarded. In that sense, if you are calling function from a loop for million times means, you are creating and discarding function frame for a million times.

Comment: @Amith I frequently implement parallelization with python's multiprocess package. A big concern is generally memory usage; on a 48 node server I find that 64 GB of memory can evaporate quickly once you spawn enough processes. I'm writing some C code in an attempt to get a better handle on the memory usage issues with my parallel processes. If I have ~40 parallel function frames each with their own heap allocated, you may have to be careful how much memory each function frame is requesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
    double d = 5;
    // some other stuff here
}
```

`d` is only allocated once by the compiler. It's mostly equivalent to declaring it above the for loop, except that the scope doesn't extend as far.

However, if you are doing something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
    double *d = malloc(sizeof(double));
    free(d);
}
```

Then yes, you will allocate a `double` 1 million times, but it will likely re-use the memory for subsequent allocations. Finally, if you don't free the memory in my second example, you'll leak 16-32MB of memory.

Comment: 8 MiB is a conservative estimate; it doesn't account for the control information for each block of memory that's allocated.  It would likely be that each leaked allocation was 16, possibly even 32 bytes in total – 8 bytes for the double, some overhead because of minimum allocation size, and some overhead for control information used by malloc et al.

Comment: The only difference is that within the for loop I call a function. That function then initializes the double. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @kingledion as long as your double is declared like the first example, yes.

Comment: Good point, but the OP writes *I declare a couple of double variables*. Pointers are not `double` variables. In any case, posting the code is required to enlighten us.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, but I wanted to show exactly what was necessary to have an allocation on each run of a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: **NO**, it should not matter if you declare these `double` variables inside the loop in C. By `double` variable, I assume you mean variables of type `double`.

The long answer is: Please post your code so people can tell you if you do something wrong and how to fix it to improve correctness and/or performance (a vast subject).

The final answer is: with the code provided, it makes no difference whether you declare `u1` and `u2` inside the body of the loop or outside. A good compiler will likely generate the same code.

You can improve the code a tiny bit by testing the odd case just once:

```
void getRandNorm(double *randnorm, double mean, double var, int n, double pi) {
    // Declare variables
    double u1, u2;
    double sigma = sqrt(var); // the standard deviation
    int arrptr, odd;

    odd = n & 1;  // check if n is odd
    n -= odd;     // make n even

    for (arrptr = 0; arrptr < n; arrptr += 2) { 
        // Generate two uniform random variables
        u1 = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        u2 = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;

        // Box-Muller transform
        randnorm[arrptr + 0] = sqrt(-2*log(u1)) * cos(2*pi*u2) * sigma + mean;
        randnorm[arrptr + 1] = sqrt(-2*log(u2)) * cos(2*pi*u1) * sigma + mean;
    }
    if (odd) {
        u1 = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        u2 = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        randnorm[arrptr++] = sqrt(-2*log(u1)) * cos(2*pi*u2) * sigma + mean;
    }
}
```

Note: `arrptr + 0` is here for symmetry, the compiler will not generate any code for this addition.

Answer (score 1):

regarding your question:  *If I run a loop a million times, do I have to worry about declaring doubles in each iteration?*

The variables are being declared on the stack.  So they 'disappear' when the function exits.  The next execution of the function 're-creates' the variables, so (in reality) there is only a single instance of the variables and even then, only while the function is being executed.

So it does not matter how many times you call the function.